# AH00534: apache2: Configuration error: No MPM loaded

Tags: apache, ubuntu-16.04

I'm running Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)

> Am facing the below error.

```
# apache2ctl -t -f /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf
AH00534: apache2: Configuration error: No MPM loaded.
Action '-t -f /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

> configtest has no errors

```
# apache2ctl configtest
Syntax OK
```

> Contents of **/var/log/apache2/error.log**

```
[core:notice] [pid 2668] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2668] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[:notice] [pid 2707] ModSecurity: ModSecurity-Apache v0.1.1-beta configured.
[mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2715] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.0g configured -- resuming normal operations
[core:notice] [pid 2715] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Most of the forums have solutions specifying to load **mod_mpm_prefork.so**

> However, It is enabled already.

```
# ls /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ | grep "prefork"
mpm_prefork.conf
mpm_prefork.load
```

> Contents of mpm_prefork.conf and mpm_prefork.load

```
# cat /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_prefork.conf

<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers             5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxRequestWorkers     150
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# cat /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_prefork.load 
# Conflicts: mpm_event mpm_worker
LoadModule mpm_prefork_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
```

> Other commands:

```
# apache2 -l
Compiled in modules:
  core.c
  mod_so.c
  mod_watchdog.c
  http_core.c
  mod_log_config.c
  mod_logio.c
  mod_version.c
  mod_unixd.c
```

Let me know how to fix this.

Comment: I had the same issue.
<br>In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48525370/2559023) post I found the enswer

Comment: thanks. that is right one!...