# Laravel docker: adsist-docker_app_1 exited with code 1

Tags: laravel, docker, centos7

im trying to set up a Laravel project.

The setup is:

- Centos
- Apache
- MySql

I have split containers for App, Web, Database

And app container is fail to run :(

This is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:

  # The Application
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: app.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    environment:
      - "DB_PORT=3306"
      - "DB_HOST=database"

  # The Web Server
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: web.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes_from:
      - app
    ports:
      - 8080:80

  # The Database
  database:
    image: mysql:5.6
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_DATABASE=homestead"
      - "MYSQL_USER=homestead"
      - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret"
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
    ports:
      - "33061:3306"

volumes:
  dbdata:
```

This is my app.dockerfile

```
FROM centos:7.5.1804

RUN yum update -y

RUN yum install epel-release http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm yum-utils -y && \
    yum-config-manager --enable remi-php72 && \
    yum update -y

RUN yum install vim wget curl unzip \
    php php-json php-gd php-mbstring php-pdo php-xml php-mysqlnd -y

RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" && \
    php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer && \
    rm -rf composer-setup.php

RUN curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - && \
    yum install nodejs -y

RUN yum clean all

EXPOSE 80

# Keep container active
CMD ["/usr/sbin/httpd", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

And this is my web.dockerfile:

```
FROM httpd:2.4

COPY httpd.conf /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

When I run `docker-compose up` shows some messages:

> app_1       | AH00526: Syntax error on line 119 of
>   /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: app_1       | DocumentRoot '/var/www/html'
>   is not a directory, or is not readable
>
> adsist-docker_app_1 exited with code 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/var/www/html` set as apache documentroot is popular in most linux distributions, but this is not the thing in `httpd` docker image. Additional, even you modify http.conf to use `/var/www/html`, you still should mount to `/var/www/html`, not `/var/www`.

And back to the `httpd` image, you could see next:

```
$ docker run -idt httpd:2.4
docker ps
CONTAINER ID    IMAGE       COMMAND              CREATED STATUS  PORTS               NAMES
182c63e24082    httpd:2.4   "httpd-foreground"   3 seconds ago   Up 1 second 80/tcp  clever_bassi
$ docker exec -it clever_bassi /bin/bash
root@182c63e24082:/usr/local/apache2/conf# cat httpd.conf
......
DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs"
......
```

So, if you do not change default settings, you should mount your host's files to `/usr/local/apache2/htdocs` to serve your service.

And more, `COPY httpd.conf /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` in your `Dockerfile` is also not correct, it should be `COPY httpd.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf`.

Comment: Thank you so much, it solved my problem! But I still have a problem with the conf file. `web_1       | AH00534: httpd: Configuration error: No MPM loaded.`

Comment: I have added this line to the conf file, but still no luck... :  `LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so`

Comment: So, I guess this related your changes on your customized `httpd.conf`. See if [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48525092/docker-httpd-configuration-error-no-mpm-loaded) help, if not, you'd better submit a separate question to draw attention who are familiar with apache.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your app will be deployed in `/var/www/` while you configure Apache to use `/var/www/html/` as a document root so while starting Apache it checks first for configured document root but it can't find it so it fails to start  and generate the mentioned error.

So you have to decide to change document root in httpd.conf to point to `/var/www/` or configure docker-compose file to work and mount volumes to `/var/www/html`.